# Static variable initialization with non static member variable

Tags: c++

In the project I am working I saw a code like below in code review process:

```
class A 
{
   shared_ptr<B> instanceB; 
}

A::A ()
{
   instanceB = make_shared<B>();
   static C localVariable(instanceB.get());
}
```

I know static variable's are like globals and will be created when program starts and instanceB will be created when A instantiated. And this may crash.

While explaining that I begin to think about what value instanceB.get() would return. Most probably garbage right? And when I think more about it 
I believe this code even shouldn't be compiled why static variables are allowed to take non-static parameters in their ctors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> and will be created when program starts

No, that's wrong. Static variables in functions are created when that function executes for the first time. Therefore, your `localVariable` will receive what `instanceB.get()` will return when `A::A()` will run for the first time. So no garbage will be in `localVariable`.

Such design might indeed look very strange, but it is syntatically correct and has a well-defined meaning for the compiler. Moreover, a very similar design is used in a classical singleton implementation.